# Google Form trigger on next

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form made of two sections.

I would like to save the answers to this form (especially time stamp) as soon as the user exits the first section (i.e. when it presses the "next" button).

I guess this is not treated as a `submit` event (at least in the docs it is never said). Is there a way to create a trigger `onNext()` which will fire as the user presses on "next", or to get at least the timestamp when it pressed it?

Comment: This is not currently possible because form elements are submitted all at once as an event object. The closest you could get to doing this is creating a second form and linking it in the submission message of part 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from one section to another is not an event for Apps Script; there is no trigger for that. The only triggers associated with Forms are [onOpen and onSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events), which respond to the form being edited, or submitted in its entirety.